# 1940's movie about a house being fakely haunted, turns out to actually be inhabited by two ghosts

Tags: story-identification, movie, ghost

I remember seeing an old 1940's B&W movie when I was a kid about a house that was supposedly haunted.

All I remember was that there was a group of people in the house and a lot of comically creepy things going on.  It turned out to be someone trying to scare everyone away from the house for some underhanded reason (a very typical haunted house plot).

I'm pretty sure this was a comedy.

The thing that I am positively sure of is that at the very end of the movie when the bad guy has finally scared everybody away and is satisfied, he suddenly sees objects moving by themselves; and since he knows it wasn't his doing, he also flees the house.  Just before "The End" comes on the screen, we see two real ghosts materialize and begin waving goodbye to us (the viewers).

Comment: This is the plotline of every single episode of Scooby Doo

Comment: @Valorum - Well, except for actual ghosts at the end. *Most* incarnations of Scooby-Doo didn't have any real ghosts/monsters.

Answer (score 3):

There are a [number of films](http://www.imdb.com/keyword/haunted-house/?title_type=feature&genre=comedy&sort=release_date) that seem to fit the bill, not least because ("Haunted house" AND "Comedy" AND "plot") is a [pretty common trope](http://www.flickchart.com/Charts.aspx?genre=Haunted%20House%20Film&decade=1940), especially for 1940s films.

Two seem like likely candidates, mostly because the title cards have pictures of ghosts on them;

[Spook Busters](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038976/)

> The Bowery Boys--Slip, Sach, Bobby, Whitey & Chuck--start their own
>   exterminating service, and get a job which takes them to a spooky old
>   abandoned mansion in the middle of the night

[image: Spook Busters]

[Ghost Catchers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0036861/)

> Colonel Breckinridge Martshall (Walter Catlett), a self-appointed
>   southern colonel, brings his two daughters,Melinda (Gloria Jean) and
>   Susanna (Martha O'Driscoll), to New York City so they can sing at
>   Carnegie Hall. He buys a haunted house from Chambers ('Walter
>   Kingsford' qv)) a crooked real estate dealer. The "ghosts" start their
>   work on the first night and Susanna runs next door to a nightclub
>   owned by Olsen (Ole Olsen) and Johnson (Chic Johnson)and they agree to
>   help her...and set out to rid the house of the ghosts.

[image: Ghost Catchers]

Comment: Good call, Spook Busters is the first thing I thought of!

Comment: Since it's been bumped back, I guess now's as good a time as any to split that into two separate answers. Just my opinion though